# Emulate massive 2x4K screen size for interactive touchscreen project

Tags: virtual-machine, touchscreen, screen-size

I'm currently working on a project for an interactive visitor space and one of the interactive screens will be two landscape 4K screens side by side with an extended/stretched desktop.

So, the total screen resolution will be 7680px x 2180px.  The application will be browser based and will allow multiple users to work with a media library and bring pictures and videos onto the screen and stretch, pan and play them and all that good stuff.

My problem is in testing this solution as we go through development.  The actual screens are in Laguna Beach, CA and we are based in London.  We can work with 1080p touchscreens, however there is nothing like testing on the real thing and I foresee difficulties.

Does anyone have any ideas how I could emulate this screen size, which would at least allow a little more confidence?  I'm thinking of virtual machines, but not sure if this will even work.

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: On which os? What kind of GV are you using? We need more informations

Comment: We are using Win 8 and probably have to use IE11 due to problems with Touch events in Chrome.

Comment: Not sure I understand 'What kind of GV'?

Comment: Graphic Card, I made a typo

Comment: We will be using an 'ATI AMD FirePro W8000 4GB GDDR5' on the final hardware, but I won't have access to this until after we have started developing.  What I need is some way of emulating this display size.  For now, I don't really care about performance.  It's more about the logistics of designing HTML for 7680px x 2180px and testing it - albeit at a slow speed.

Answer (score 0):

Try following this. http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003

Good luck!